# What word/phrase includes furniture,home appliances, architectural features?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Is there any word or phrase like that?

Example:

> Ichikawa’s in a one-bedroom apartment with typical __: table, futon,
>   refrigerator, bathroom.

I can't use furniture because of refrigerator and bathroom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word that's closest to what you're looking for would probably be [**furnishings**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/furnishing):

> Furniture, fittings, and other decorative accessories, such as curtains and carpets, for a house or room.
>
> Example:
>
> *In the end, the cost of the house and its furnishings totaled more than one million dollars.*

Who knows, maybe there is a more specific term for this where seemingly different things such as a refrigerator and a bathroom do fall under the same category. I can't really think of one word that would encompass all of furniture, appliances and rooms like that. The term [**amenities**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amenity) is possible, but I'm not sure if a table can be considered an amenity. For example:

> His apartment has all the typical amenities: modern furniture, bathroom, refrigerator etc.

You could also say *all the typical conveniences*.